# Office.js Add-In Taskpane Not Changing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, dom, office-js

Okay so I'm currently trying to develop an add-in for Excel using the Office JS Api stuff.  I'm using Visual Studio 2017 so that I can use the JS console that got removed from VS 2019.  It's been working fine up until now, but all of a sudden, when I attempt to run the add-in and test the changes I've made, the Taskpane that is created is the same as it's been the past several changes ago.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it change.

Any changes to the Home.html file, which should trigger the change, does nothing.  The DOM explorer window that pops up confirms that its the same Home.html it's had the past several times, not the updated one I wrote.  I really don't know what troubleshooting steps to even take.  Judging by the build output and the JS output, nothing is doing anything wrong.

Additional:  Swapping back to Visual Studio 2019 does not make a difference.  Going to Build > Rebuild Solution also does not remedy the situation.  I'll be re-cloning my repo and attempting to run it as a fresh project to see if that makes a difference.  Result:  Didn't fix it.